# Как правильно проверить свойство коллекцию на правильность ввода!

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Мне нужно проверать все свойства класса **OfferModel**.

Проблема в том что нужно проверить:**Picture**,**Descriptions**,**Param** как это коллекции а не свойства.

Например:как проверить свойство коллекцию Descriptions.Text на пустоту(то есть пользователь ввел данные все ок если это не так textbox становиться крассый я это делаю спомощью **IDataErrorInfo**)  и проверить коллекции есть элементы Descriptions.Count()>0 тогда кнопка выключена.

То есть если  Descriptions.Count()>0 в коллекции больше 0 элементов и если элементы  все свойства пустые Descriptions.Text  деактивировать кнопку  или Descriptions.Count() != 0 и все свойства Descriptions.Text не пустые активировать кнопку.

[Этот пример я использовал для проверки валидации данных](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM) У меня есть модели коллекции и я не знаю как проверять на валидацию данных.

**OfferModel**

```
class OfferModel:ChangeProperty,IDataErrorInfo
    {
        #region Cвойства
        string url { get; set; }
        public string Url
        {
            get { return url; }
            set
            {
                url = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Url");
            }
        }

        decimal price { get; set; }
        public decimal Price
        {
            get { return price; }
            set
            {
                price = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Price");
            }
        }

        string currencyId { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyId
        {
            get { return currencyId; }
            set
            {
                currencyId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrencyId");
            }
        }

        int categoryId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId
        {
            get { return categoryId; }
            set
            {
                categoryId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CategoryId");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Picture { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        string name { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        string vendor { get; set; }
        public string Vendor
        {
            get { return vendor; }
            set
            {
                vendor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Vendor");
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel> Descriptions { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DescriptionModel>();
        public ObservableCollection<ParamModel> Param { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ParamModel>();
       
        int stock_quantity { get; set; }
        public int Stock_quantity
        {
            get { return stock_quantity; }
            set
            {
                stock_quantity = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Stock_quantity");
            }
        }

        bool аvailable { get; set; }
        public bool Available
        {
            get { return аvailable; }
            set
            {
                аvailable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Available");
            }
        }

        int id { get; set; }
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Проверка свойств
        string er { get; set; }
        public string Error
        {
            get { return er; }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        validationResult = Validation.Name(Name);
                        break;
                    case "Url":
                        validationResult = Validation.Ui(Url);
                        break;
                    case "Price":
                        validationResult = Validation.Price(Price);
                        break;
                    case "Vendor":
                        validationResult = Validation.Vendor(Vendor);
                        break;
                    case "Stock_quantity":
                        validationResult = Validation.StockQuantity(Stock_quantity);
                        break;
                    default:throw new ApplicationException("Неизвестное свойство проверяется модели OfferModel.");
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        public OfferModel(){}
        public OfferModel(string url, decimal price, string currencyId, int categoryId, string name, string vendor, int stock_quantity, bool available, int id)
        {
            Url = url;
            Price = price;
            CurrencyId = currencyId;
            CategoryId = categoryId;
            Name = name;
            Vendor = vendor;
            Stock_quantity = stock_quantity;
            Available = available;
            Id = id;
        }
 
    }
```

**ParamModel**

```
class ParamModel :ChangeProperty,IDataErrorInfo
    {
        string name { get; set; }
        string text { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Xарактеристику параметра.
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Значение параметра.
        /// </summary>
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Text");
            }
        }


        public ParamModel() { }
        public ParamModel(string name, string text)
        {
            Name = name;
            Text = text;
        }

        #region Проверка свойств
        string er { get; set; }
        public string Error
        {
            get { return er; }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        validationResult = Validation.NameParam(Name);
                        break;
 
                    case "Text":
                        validationResult = Validation.TextParam(Text);
                        break;
                    default:throw new ApplicationException("Неизвестное свойство проверяется модели ParamModel.");
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }
        #endregion


    }
```

**DescriptionModel**

```
class DescriptionModel:ChangeProperty,IDataErrorInfo
    {
      
        private string text { get; set; }
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set 
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
            }
        }
        public DescriptionModel() { }
        public DescriptionModel(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

        #region Проверка свойств
        string er { get; set; }
        public string Error
        {
            get { return er; }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {
                string validationResult = null;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Text":
                        validationResult = Validation.Text(Text);
                        break;
                    default: throw new ApplicationException("Неизвестное свойство проверяется модели DescriptionModel.");
                }
                return validationResult;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

Как  я проверяю **AddProductViewModel** свойство коллекцию при дабавлении товара: Picture.CollectionChanged-при добавлении в коллекцию,item.PropertyChanged-при изменении свойств.

Это хорошо когда событие сработало CollectionChanged(то есть при добавлении в коллекцию,ну если  offer передать по ссылке в конструктор для измерения товара событие не сработает CollectionChanged).

Есть другой способ реализации проверки?

```
 readonly OfferModel offer;
 /// <summary>
        /// Хранения валлидность свойств.
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<string, bool> validProperties;
        /// <summary>
        /// Включить кнопку если все свойства валлидни.
        /// </summary>
        private bool allPropertiesValid = false;
        public bool AllPropertiesValid
        {
            get { return allPropertiesValid; }
            set
            {
                if (allPropertiesValid != value)
                {
                    allPropertiesValid = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("AllPropertiesValid");
                }
            }
        }
 #region Валидации данных
            validProperties = new Dictionary<string, bool>();//нужен для того чтобы включить кнопку добавленные если все данные будут коректные.
            validProperties.Add("Name", false);
            validProperties.Add("Url", false);
            validProperties.Add("Price", false);
            validProperties.Add("Vendor", false);
            validProperties.Add("Stock_quantity", false);
            validProperties.Add("Picture", false);
            validProperties.Add("Descriptions", false);
            validProperties.Add("Param", false);
            //Проверки на валидность ввода Picture Descriptions Param.
            Picture.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                validProperties["Picture"] = Picture.Count() > 0 ? true : false;
                ValidateProperties();
            };
            Descriptions.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {

                bool isEmpty = false;
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (DescriptionModel item in e.NewItems)//Добавление новые элементы
                    {
                        isEmpty = Validation.TextBool(item.Text) ? false : true;
                        item.PropertyChanged += (sender, argument) => //Проходимся по свойствам модели.
                        {
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (var des in Descriptions)
                            {
                                if (Validation.TextBool(des.Text))
                                {
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            validProperties["Descriptions"] = (i == 0) ? true : false;
                            isEmpty = (i == 0) ? true : false;
                            ValidateProperties();

                        };

                    }
                }
                else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var des in Descriptions)
                    {
                        if (Validation.TextBool(des.Text))
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    isEmpty = (i == 0) ? true : false;
                }

                validProperties["Descriptions"] = (Descriptions.Count > 0 && isEmpty != false) ? true : false;
                ValidateProperties();
            };
            Param.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                bool isEmpty = false;
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (ParamModel item in e.NewItems)//Добавление новые элементы
                    {

                        var name = Validation.NameBoolParam(item.Name);
                        var text = Validation.TextBoolParam(item.Text);
                        validProperties["Param"] = (name && text) ?  false: true;
                        item.PropertyChanged += (sender, argument) => //Проходимся по свойствам модели.
                        {
                            int nameisvalid = 0;
                            int textisvalid = 0;
                            foreach (var par in Param)//Ищем неправильно заполнены параметры.
                            {
                                if (Validation.NameBoolParam(par.Name)) nameisvalid++;
                                if (Validation.TextBoolParam(par.Text)) textisvalid++;
                            }
                            validProperties["Param"] = (nameisvalid == 0 && textisvalid == 0) ? true : false;
                            isEmpty = (nameisvalid == 0 && textisvalid == 0) ? true : false;
                            ValidateProperties();

                        };

                    }
                }
                else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    int nameisvalid = 0;
                    int textisvalid = 0;
                    foreach (var par in Param)
                    {
                        if (Validation.NameBoolParam(par.Name)) nameisvalid++;
                        if (Validation.TextBoolParam(par.Text)) textisvalid++;
                    }
                    isEmpty = (nameisvalid == 0 && textisvalid == 0) ? true : false;
                }

                validProperties["Param"] = (Param.Count > 0 && isEmpty != false) ? true : false;
                ValidateProperties();
            };
            #endregion


#region Реализация IDataErrorInfo 

        public string Error
        {
            get { return (offer as IDataErrorInfo).Error; }
        }

        public string this[string propertyName]
        {
            get
            {   if(offer != null)
                {
                    string error = (offer as IDataErrorInfo)[propertyName];
                    validProperties[propertyName] = string.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? true : false;
                    ValidateProperties();
                    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
                    return error;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void ValidateProperties()
        {
            foreach (bool isValid in validProperties.Values)
            {
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    AllPropertiesValid = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
            AllPropertiesValid = true;
        }

        #endregion
```

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но мне кажется для вопроса тут слишком много кода. Чтобы кто-то мог тебе помоч, он болжен сначала во всём этом разбираться , при этом не зная, для чего вообще это нужно, но с такой кучей кода мало кто захочет разбираться и тратить на это много времени (по сравнению с ответом на среднестатистический вопрос). Лучше выделить тут основную часть и выкладывать только её.

Comment: @Мурад  я тут и так только основное выложил

Comment: Вы очень непонятно пишете. Я понимаю, что русский язык может быть вам не родной, и вам тоже тяжело излагать свои мысли на этом языке, но я прошу вас попытаться улучшить текст вопроса, не просто с точки зрения грамотности, а вставить пропущенные слова. Пожалуйста, перечитайте свой вопрос и внесите исправления. В текущем состоянии я понять его не могу.

Comment: @aepot я все исравил,наример:грубо говоря нужно проверять свойство коллекцию:в коллекции должен быть хотябы 1 элемет Descriptions.Cout()>0 и все свойства должны быть не пустые Descriptions.Text  тогда можно активировать кнопку для сохранение товара или не активировать.Нужно сделать так пока пользователь не ввел все данные.

Comment: Декорируйте свойства стандартными атрибутами ValidationAttribute, либо создайте свои и используйте их для проверки.

Comment: @XelaNimed  как такое можно сделать я только недавно начал изучать валидацию данных??

Comment: если у вас есть пример буду благодарен!?

Comment: Реализуйте IDataErrorInfo

Comment: @Vladimir только сильно не пинайте... https://dotnetfiddle.net/enNJ52 Если Вам так подойдёт, то могу оформить как ответ. P.S.: но скорее всего, лучше знающих людей подождать, т.к. я не уверен правильно ли это...

Comment: @XelaNimed я все понял 50 на 50 ну в  проблема том  я не понял  как проверять коллекции  например: если Descriptions.Count() == 0 в коллекции 0 элементов или если  свойства пустые Descriptions.Text тогда это ошибка.

Comment: Если необходимого Вам функционала нет в стандартных ValidationAttributes, то Вы всегда можете реализовать свой.

Comment: @XelaNimed Мне понять как это  сделать!

Comment: @Vladimir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780943/how-to-create-custom-validation-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этих целей существуют атрибуты [ValidationAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=netcore-3.1). Если необходимо реализовать какую-либо особенную проверку свойства, то можно:

- [создать свой атрибут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-attributes)
- [реализовать интерфейс IValidatableObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ivalidatableobject) для проверки всего типа. В этом случае можно будет использовать [Validator](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator?view=netframework-4.7.2).
- [использовать CustomValidationAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) для вызова статического метода с сигнатурой:

  1. ValidationResult Method(object)
  2. ValidationResult Method(object, ValidationContext)

После этого мы можем использовать рефлексию для проверки. Использование может выглядеть так:

```cs
public static class StaticValidators
{
    public static ValidationResult IsUpperCase(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(Res.IsUpper_ValueIsNull, new string[] { context.MemberName });
        }

        string strValue = value.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(Res.IsUpper_ValueIsEmpty, new string[] { context.MemberName });
        }

        bool _isEquals = string.Equals(strValue, strValue.ToUpperInvariant(), StringComparison.InvariantCulture);

        return _isEquals
            ? ValidationResult.Success
            : new ValidationResult(Res.IsUpper_ValueIsNotValid, new string[] { context.MemberName });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false),
        StringLength(10),
        RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z-]+$")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false),
        StringLength(10),
        RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z-]+$")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false),
        CustomValidation(typeof(StaticValidators), method: nameof(StaticValidators.IsUpperCase))]
    public string PersonalNr { get; set; }

    [ContainsUnique(typeof(string))]
    public List<string> Emails { get; set; }

    [ContainsUnique(typeof(PhoneNumber), PropertyName = nameof(PhoneNumber.TypeOfPhone))]
    public List<PhoneNumber> Phones { get; set; }
}

public struct PhoneNumber
{
    public string NumberOfPhone { get; set; }
    public PhoneType TypeOfPhone { get; set; }
}

var person = new Person
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    PersonalNr = "Abc123",
    Emails = new List<string>
    {
        "example@domain.tld", "j.doe@gmail.com", "jd@yahoo.com", "j.doe@gmail.com"
    },
    Phones = new List<PhoneNumber>
    {
        new PhoneNumber{ NumberOfPhone = "123", TypeOfPhone = PhoneType.PrivateMobile },
        new PhoneNumber{ NumberOfPhone = "567", TypeOfPhone = PhoneType.PrivateMobile }
    }
};

var result = person.ValidateType();
/*
result is:
[{
  "PropertyName": "PersonalNr",
  "AttributeName": "RegularExpressionAttribute",
  "ErrorMessage": "The field PersonalNr must match the regular expression '^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}$'."
},
{
  "PropertyName": "Emails",
  "AttributeName": "ContainsUniqueAttribute",
  "ErrorMessage": "Поле Emails не должно содержать повторяющихся значений в свойстве 'value'. Дубликаты значений: j.doe@gmail.com."
},
{
  "PropertyName": "Phones",
  "AttributeName": "ContainsUniqueAttribute",
  "ErrorMessage": "Поле Phones не должно содержать повторяющихся значений в свойстве 'TypeOfPhone'. Дубликаты значений: PrivateMobile."
}]
*/
```

Пример реализации атрибута валидации:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class MinCountAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public uint MinCount { get; }

    public MinCountAttribute(uint minCount)
    {
        MinCount = minCount;
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(AttributesResources);
        ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(AttributesResources.MinCount_ValidationError);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, MinCount);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value is null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (value is ICollection collection)
        {
            return MinCount <= (collection?.Count ?? -1);
        }
        throw new InvalidCastException(AttributesResources.MinCount_InvalidCastException);
    }
}
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [демо-проект](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypt54ap8av4xs1w/ConsoleAppCore1.zip?dl=0)
- [IValidatableObject Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [ValidationAttribute Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- [CustomValidationAttribute Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- исходный код [CustomValidationAttribute.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/CustomValidationAttribute.cs)

---

P.S.: извиняюсь. Только сейчас понял, что речь идёт о WPF. В таком случае [вот этот ответ поможет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42565534/3129992).

Comment: Спасибо вам вы помогли понять что нужно изучить!)